# How do I change my mutation to accept an array of IDs instead of a single ID?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, cart, graphql-js, keystonejs

I have a cart for anonymous users and would like to pass the cart into the database with a mutation. I've created a test but can't pass multiple values all at once. I end up with an error like…

```
[GraphQL error]: Message: Variable "$id" got invalid value ["87b7dsfg6ds78ga", "36b34b5hb5hjbj23b", "36b34b5hb5hjbj23b"]; ID cannot represent value: ["87b7dsfg6ds78ga", "36b34b5hb5hjbj23b", "36b34b5hb5hjbj23b"],
```

This is my mutation:

```js
const ADD_TO_CART_MUTATION = gql`
  mutation ADD_TO_CART_MUTATION($id: ID!) {
    addToCart(productId: $id) {
      id
    }
  }
`;

export default function SendToCartButton() {
    var cartItems = useReactiveVar(cartItemsVar);
    console.log(cartItems)

    const [sendToCart] = useMutation(ADD_TO_CART_MUTATION, {
        variables: { id: cartItems },
        refetchQueries: [{ query: CURRENT_USER_QUERY }],
    });

    return (
        <div className="add-to-cart-button" >
            <CartButton onClick={sendToCart}>
                Send To Cart db
            </CartButton>
        </div>
    );
}
```

I have tried configuring the mutation as [ID]! but get:

```
[GraphQL error]: Message: Variable "$id" of type "[ID!]" used in position expecting type "ID"., Location: [object Object],[object Object], Path: undefined
```

Can anyone explain what I need to do please?

Thank you!

Comment: Thank you @Manny. That is passing multiple values but my new error is:

`Error: Variable "$where" got invalid value { in: ["87b7dsfg6ds78ga", "87b7dsfg6ds78ga"] } at "where.AND[1].product.id"; ID cannot represent value: { in: ["87b7dsfg6ds78ga", "87b7dsfg6ds78ga"] }`

Comment: You've included code where you _call_ the custom mutation but not the code where the mutation itself is defined. Where's your call to `extendGraphqlSchema`?

Comment: In case anyone's looking for it – currently, the best docs on the `extendGraphqlSchema()` functionality are in the example project that demos it: https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone/tree/master/examples/extend-graphql-schema

Comment: Hi, so in the end I used this in the frontend:

`const …
  mutation ADD_TO_CART_MUTATION($id: [ID]!) {
    sendToCart(productIds: $id) {
…`

and in the backend:

`async function sendToCart(
    root: any,
    { productIds }: { productIds: string[] },
    context: KeystoneContext
): Promise<void> {
    const sesh = context.session;

const quantities = []
    productIds.forEach(function (x) { quantities[x] = (quantities[x] || 0) + 1; });
    {
        Object.entries(quantities).map(async ([key, value]) => {

// rest of code …`

Answer (score 1):

so in the end I used this in the frontend:

```
const …
  mutation ADD_TO_CART_MUTATION($id: [ID]!) {
    sendToCart(productIds: $id) {
…
```

with

```
sendToCart({
    variables: {
        id: cartItems,
    },
});
```

and in the backend:

```
async function sendToCart(
    root: any,
    { productIds }: { productIds: string[] },
    context: KeystoneContext
): Promise<void> {
    const sesh = context.session;

const quantities = []
    productIds.forEach(function (x) { quantities[x] = (quantities[x] || 0) + 1; });
    {
        Object.entries(quantities).map(async ([key, value]) => {

// rest of code …
```

Answer (score 0):

Making use of `[ID!]!`

- states that input will be a list of Type ID that cannot have any null entries and `$id` cannot be null

```
const ADD_TO_CART_MUTATION = gql`
  mutation ADD_TO_CART_MUTATION($id: [ID!]!) {
   ...
  }
`;
```